# Converting coordinates of a point (lat/lng) to coordinates of the "radius-rectangle"

Tags: php

I´m having a point on a map given by its latitude and longitude. In my function I want to search "around" this point. This function needs the top right corner and the bottom left corner of a "search-rectangle" in order to perform the search. The one point should be in the center of the rectangle. In fact I´m defining a radius of X km around this point.

The two points of the rectangle are defined by:

Top-Right: nort-east-latitude and north-east longitude.
Bottom-Left: southwest-latiude and southwest-longitude.

Question: How can I convert the point coordinates to the 4 rectangle-points coordinates (relative to radius X)?

Comment: Isn't it just adding and subtracting the distance from the center point to get the point top-right and the point bottom-left? What is the problem you have? What is the source code you have?

Comment: ...turns out to be true. lol. Ive just converted the km of the radius to degrees and added or subtracted it to the given coordinates. rediculous :D this might not be the perfect solution but for me needs its aboslutely okay. other links discussin this problem:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19760/how-do-i-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-given-a-distance-and-latitude-longitude
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19221/find-tangent-point-on-circle-furthest-east-or-west